# Django model accessed globally

Tags: django

I want to have a model accessed throughout the whole project in the templates, **not to declare it on every view**. Is this possible? What is the best way to do this?

Something like User is accessed through `request.user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a  ***context processor***, here is a list of [built-ins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#built-in-template-context-processors) in Django. Basically, this is how `User` is global in Django.

Also, for a great article follow this [link](https://djangobook.com/writing-context-processors/).